# Hiding content for validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Good Afternoon everyone.

I have a custom validation to check the word count but I would like to know if there is a way of hiding content in the view depending on validation pass/fail.

Here is what I have so far:

_

```
form.html.erb

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>

  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @book.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Type:</strong>
  <%= @book.size %>
</p>

 <div id="snippets">


         <%= render :partial => @book.snippets %>


 </div>
 <% if size_limit = true %>
    <h2>Comments Closed</h2>
    <% else %>
<%= form_for [@book, @snippet] do |f| %>
        <p>
                <%= f.label :title, "New comment" %><br/>
                <%= f.text_area :content %>
        </p>
        <p><%= f.submit "Create Snippet" %></p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(@book) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>
```

Would I need to define something in the controller?

**Amended Code - Not working**

```
<% if @book.snippet.errors.blank? %>
    <%= form_for [@book, @snippet] do |f| %>
        <p>
                <%= f.label :title, "New comment" %><br/>
                <%= f.text_area :content %>
        </p>
        <p><%= f.submit "Create Snippet" %></p>
<% end %>
    <% else %>
    <h2>Comments Closed</h2>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(@book) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', books_path %>
```

Custom Validation:

```
 validate :size_limit


  BOOK_SIZE = { 
    0 => {"per" => 50, "total" => 50},
    1 => {"per" => 6 , "total" => 60},
    2 => {"per" => 7, "total" => 70}
  }   

   def  size_limit
    book_limit = self.book.size
    word_count = self.content.scan(/\w+/).size
    current_snippets_size = (self.book.get_word_count || 0) + word_count
    errors.add(:content, "Content size is too big") unless word_count < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per'] && current_snippets_size < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['total']
  end
```

Error Test:

```
irb(main):022:0> b = Book.last
  ←[1m←[36mBook Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "books".* FROM "books" ORDER BY "books"."id" DESC LIMIT 1←[0m
=> #<Book id: 14, title: "AAAA", size: 0, created_at: "2013-10-21 10:49:07", updated_at: "2013-10-21 10:49:07", approved: false, t
otal: nil, cat: "Sci-Fi">
irb(main):023:0> snip = b.snippets.create({:content => "Hell"})
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  begin transaction
  ←[1m←[36mBook Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."id" = ? ORDER BY "books"."id" ASC LIMIT 1←[0m
[["id", 14]]
  ←[1m←[35mSnippet Load (0.0ms)←[0m  SELECT "snippets".* FROM "snippets" WHERE "snippets"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 14]]
  ←[1m←[36m (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mcommit transaction←[0m
=> #<Snippet id: nil, content: "Hell", book_id: 14, approved: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):024:0> snip.valid?
=> false
irb(main):025:0> snip.errors.blank?
=> false
irb(main):026:0> snip.errors
=> #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x5aada18 @base=#<Snippet id: nil, content: "Hell", book_id: 14, approved: nil, created_at: nil, updated_
at: nil>, @messages={:content=>["Content size is too big"]}>
```

Comment: Your view looks ok. My best guess is that there is something wrong with your custom validation method. Try creating an invalid snippet in console. Is the size_limit method behaving as expected?

Comment: Yes I'll add the code from the console to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Which part of view you want to hide after validation fails?

Comment: The partial form for adding Snippet.

Comment: you can simply do this in your view file                                           if <% @book.errors.blank? %>     <%= render :partial => @book.snippets %> <% end %>

Comment: That will hide all my snippets. I want to stop people from being able to see the form input (Snippet.new) on validation fail?

Comment: what is the ralationship between book and snippet?

Comment: Snippet is a nested model of Book but the validation sits in the snippet model.

Comment: then use if @book.snippet.errors.blank? where input filed will be shown end

Comment: I've added the code you suggested to the question, I tried this before but couldn't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: what type of validation you have put ?